# HP DV6 3032-TX won't boot

Tags: laptop

Bought this overpriced, heavy, overheated laptop 13 months ago, right, 1 month pass warranty, I rarely use it, especially for last 4,5 months, didn't even turn it on, and today, I found out it won't boot, just windows 7 welcome page hanging.

I used F11 to recover, it gives me two options" launch startup repair" and "start windows normally", when I select first one, it then says " windows failed to start, a recent hard ware or software change might be the cause", 1 insert windows installation disc..... 2 choose language... 3 click repair your computer ". I put in a windows 7 disk, it will load the files, but can't reach the blue page where you select options.

I then use F2 to bring up HP system diagnostics, and it does multiple tests, and when it checks hard disk, it says failed.

My question is do I order a recovery disk from HP and try recover from the disk as I didn't have or burn the disk myself.Or it's definitely a hard disk failure, then should I still contact HP to buy a hard disk that contains windows 7 image or just buy a hard disk elsewhere, and install a retail windows 7 disk. I just want to minimise the cost as I am not sure whether same things is gonna happen again. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Buy your hard disk locally it will less expensive, then [order Recovery Media from HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00810334&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en) to re-install the OS on the new hard drive.

HP does not sell hard drives with the OS pre-installed.

[Your DV6 Service Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02657339.pdf)

[Main page for your DV6](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=4188709&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&query=DV6%203032-TX&tool=)